# Update record in table with array value

Tags: postgresql, go

I am trying to update a record in a postgres table with an array (slice) of values. The table has the following DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE slm_files (
    id uuid DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() PRIMARY KEY,
    filename character varying NOT NULL,
    status character varying NOT NULL,
    original_headers text[]
);
```

and the Go code I have is as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "database/sql"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
    "github.com/lib/pq"
)

type message struct {
    ID              string   `json:"id"`
    Filename        string   `json:"filename"`
    Status          string   `json:"status"`
    OriginalHeaders []string `json:"OriginalHeaders"`
}

func main() {
    host := os.Getenv("PGhost")
    port := 5432
    user := os.Getenv("PGuser")
    password := os.Getenv("PGpassword")
    dbname := os.Getenv("PGdbname")

    pgConString := fmt.Sprintf("port=%d host=%s user=%s "+
        "password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable",
        port, host, user, password, dbname)

    msgBody := `update_headers___
  {
      "id": "76b67119-d8c1-4a20-b53e-49e4972e2f19",
      "filename": "SLM1171_inputData_preNCOA-5babc88b-1d14-468d-bf6e-c3b36ce90d95.csv",
      "status": "Submitted",
      "OriginalHeaders": [
          "city",
          "state",
          "zipcode",
          "full_name",
          "individual_id"
      ]
  }`
    fmt.Println("Processing file", msgBody)
    queryMethod := strings.Split(msgBody, "___")[0]
    fieldDict := strings.Split(msgBody, "___")[1]

    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", pgConString)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Connected Successfully")
    defer db.Close()

    body := message{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(fieldDict), &body)
    fmt.Println(queryMethod)
    fmt.Println(body)

    var sqlStatement string
    switch queryMethod {
    case "update_ncoa":
        sqlStatement = fmt.Sprintf(`UPDATE slm_files SET status = '%s', updated_at = '%s' where id = '%s';`,
            body.Status,
            body.UpdatedAt,
            body.ID,
        )
    case "update_headers":
        sqlStatement = fmt.Sprintf(`UPDATE slm_files SET original_headers = '%s', updated_at = '%s' where id = '%s';`,
            pq.Array(body.OriginalHeaders),
            body.UpdatedAt,
            body.ID,
        )
    }
    fmt.Println(sqlStatement)
    _, err = db.Query(sqlStatement)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to run query", err)
        return
    }
}
    fmt.Println("Query executed!")
    return
}
```

but I keep getting the error

```
pq: malformed array literal: "&[first_name last_name city state zipcode full_name individual_id]": Error
null
```

I have read a few things on the internet that lead me to using `pq.Array()` but that doesnt seem to work.

I have read about the difference in format between Go arrays and Postgres arrays, so I had hoped that letting the pq.Array function would sort it out but apparently not.

Comment: Don't use Sprintf to construct SQL queries, at least not for the dynamic values. That opens the door for SQL injections. Use placeholders and the variadic arguments to Exec instead, as shown in [the docs](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/lib/pq#hdr-Queries).

Comment: thank you, I know it is not best practice but this is legacy code that is not mine and I just need to do this one thing

Comment: It's not just best practice, it's also about correctness. Sprintf doesn't produce valid SQL syntax, so it's not going to work. You have to rewrite the code.

Answer (score 0):

As Peter advised, there's a lot to fix up with that database handling. And it's definitely worth redoing those SQL statements to not use Sprintf to make the query.

But in terms of just getting something working with postgres arrays and the pq library, you need to use the Value() method of pq.Array to get the postgres format. Change your update statement for the headers to something like this:

```
arrayVal, _ := pq.Array(body.OriginalHeaders).Value()
sqlStatement = fmt.Sprintf(`UPDATE slm_files SET original_headers = '%s', updated_at = '%s' where id = '%s';`,
        arrayVal,
        body.UpdatedAt,
        body.ID,
    )
```

And it's worth checking the return from the Value() method to make sure there are no errors, I just ignored it for the sake of a simple example.